# Can the change of .dbml file influence view's validation in Asp.Net MVC 3 app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, linq-to-sql

I have lots of views in my asp.net mvc 3 application where the forms are validated. On some stage I've noticed that validation stoped working (everywhere).

I can't recall what I've done since that time. Besides I tried to move backwords to previous repository commits and seems like the problem occured long time ago, and I've noticed this only now!!

The only thing I'm sure about is that I had to change database many times so I cleaned the .dbml file and drag and drop my tables again and again (many times).

I use Linq to SQL. Most views are generated with "Edit" template. In "WebStore.designer.cs" file ("WebStore" is a project name) I use [Required] attributes. Anyway, doesn't work!

So, can the change of .dbml file influence view's validation?

Thank You in advance!

**Edits:**

For example here is the view:

```
@model WebStore.WebStoreModels.Post   

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PostId)

    <div>Title</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>

    <div>Text</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
}
```

If I don't fill the form and click "Save" I will get an SqlException in my Data Context wrapper (where I save the updated post):

```
public void UpdatePost(Post post)
    {
        var dbPost = GetPost(post.PostId);
        dbPost.Title = post.Title;
        dbPost.Text = post.Text;
        _dataContext.SubmitChanges(); // here the exception occures
    }
```

Validation just doesn't work! Code chunk from WebStore.designer.cs :

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Post title is required")]
public string Title
{ // here goes the content of this Post's property }
```

**Edits (2):**

Here are two action methods:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult EditPost(int id)
    {
        var post = _postsRepository.GetPost(id);
        return View(post);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public RedirectToRouteResult EditPost(Post post)
    {
        _postsRepository.UpdatePost(post);
        return RedirectToAction("NewsFeed");
    }
```

Comment: It all depends.  Please post some code so that we can see what is happening and can help.

Comment: @M.Ob. I provided some code above

Comment: Can you post the code of the controller method that handles the post?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check the validity of your model state prior to calling UpdatePost()
i.e.

```
[HttpPost]
public RedirectToRouteResult EditPost(Post post)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return this.View(model);
    }
    else
    {
        _postsRepository.UpdatePost(post);
        return RedirectToAction("NewsFeed");
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.